# Extracting the 'speso(A, Y, Z)' line from database for further processing

Tags: list, prolog

I have this database:

```
g([data(30, agosto, domenica),
   iniziato(16.45, audi, garage),
   s(17.45, pzzaDelGesu47, cpo, clienteA, pOnline),
   speso(81, gasolio, audi),
   s(19.45, fco, rexHotel, clientB, 40),
   s(21.25, fco, ripettaRelais, clienteC, 40),
   speso(4, parcheggio, adr),
   speso(11, lavaggio, viano),
   finito(23.00, audi, garage)]).
```

I want to extract the lines `speso(X, Y, Z)` for further processing of the data in it.

```
speseG(Date, Month, ListOfSpese) :- 
   g([data(Date, Month, _)|Tail]),
   speseGAcc(Tail, [], ListOfSpese).

speseGAcc([H|T], Acc, Res) :- 
   H = speso(Amount, What, WhichCar),
   speseGAcc(T, [H|Acc], Res).
speseGAcc([H|T], Acc, Res) :-
   speseGAcc(T, Acc, Res).
speseGAcc([], Res, Res).
```

Instead of doing this (in my opinion not efficient) is there a way to extract the `speso(X, Y, Z)` info with the help of member only?

Comment: A real mess. At least, try to put correct syntax in your question...

Comment: The problem with `member(spent(Amount, R, C), g(TheListOfDataBase))` is that `g(TheListOfDataBase)` doesn't return a value as if it were a function. You have to query it: `g(TheListOfDataBase), member(spent(Amount, R, C), TheLIstOfDataBase), ...`. Also, your database example, as it stands (both times you posted it) has at least one syntax error in it.

Comment: Please, go ahead and read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is.

Comment: If you're looking for a better way to extract the `spent` information, I think you should restructure your data so it's not in a list format. Instead, define a fact for each `spent` item. If you are looking to only extract data for a given day, then the day (or date) should be one of the arguments for the fact so it can be properly selected with a query. But if you want the data to be structured as you have it, then you're likely not going to anything more effective than using `member/2` (or `memberchk/2`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to find all the members from your facts `g` that has the functor `speso`.
You can do this using the meta-predicate [findall/3](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=findall/3).

```
?- findall(P, (g(List), member(P, List), P=..[speso|_] ), Result).
```

The result look like this for your current database sample:

```
Result = [speso(81, gasolio, audi), speso(4, parcheggio, adr), speso(11, lavaggio, viano)]
```

Also, you should follow all the recommendation posted before, to achieve a better structured knowledge database

Comment: Thanks Yasel. Your suggestion helps me a lot.

Comment: Great @vincent, I'm glad to hear it. If you think the answer is the right one and can help others, please, mark it as accepted.